# Handle dynamic text in feature file with cucumber-protractor frame work

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor-cucumber frame work with protractor 52.2 and cucumber 3.2.1.My feature file having 2 scenarios.In first scenario, i have to create a task which having unique name.
In second scenario,i have to search the newly created task by its name(i have to use the newly created task name in next scenarios).My problem is ,i am hard coding the task name in the feature file,so that when i run the same script for the second time, it becomes fail.
Because task cannot be created with same name.My feature file is given below

```
scenario:create task
When I enter name "task1" 
And I set start date "1-2-2018"
And I set end date "16-2-2018"
Then I click on "submit"

scenario:search task
When I enter "task1" in searchbox
Then I should see the "task1" in the result
```

Here the "task1" should be a dynamic text.It should change when i run the script each time. How can we resolve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) In scenario 1, generate a unique task name and store the name into `global`, like:

```
global.taskName = xxxxx
```

Step 2)  In scenario 2, access the task name from `global`, like:

```
var taskName_ele = element(by.xxx(yyy));
taskName_ele.clear().then(function(){
   taskName_ele.sendKeys(global.taskName);
})
```

**Shortage:** If you have another scenario will also change `global.taskName` and you run scenario in parallel, scenario will get dirty data of `global.taskName`.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario Outline: scenario description

```
    Given a precondition has value <param_1>

    And something with <param_2>

    Then check <param_3> is the output

    Examples:
    | param_1 | param_2 | param_3 |
    | value1_1 | value1_2 | value1_3 |
    | value2_1 | value2_2 | value2_3 |
    | value3_1 | value3_2 | value3_3 |
```